# How to get the exact Boolean value from a database (Firebase Cloud Firestore) and not the initial value from data class constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]

This is the data class constructor.

[image]

This is the value from firestore

[image]

Here on the adapter am toasting the bool value and it returns 'false' as opposed to 'true' which is from the database.

If I log an other field value from the database, it shows the correct value from the database

What could be the issue?

This the code am using to get the games

[image]

The entire adapter code is here

```
class OneTwoAdapter(
    private val oneTwoGames: MutableList<Game>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OneTwoViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OneTwoViewHolder {
        return OneTwoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.one_two_games_layout, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OneTwoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val gameDetail = oneTwoGames[position]

        holder.awayTeamName.text = gameDetail.awayTeam
        holder.gameDate.text = gameDetail.gameDate
        holder.league.text = gameDetail.league
        holder.homeTeamName.text = gameDetail.homeTeam
        holder.kickOff.text = gameDetail.kickOff
        holder.outCome.text = gameDetail.outCome
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(gameDetail.homeImageUrl)
            .into(holder.homeTeamImgUrl)
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(gameDetail.awayImageUrl)
            .into(holder.awayTeamImgUrl)
        

        Toast.makeText(
            holder.itemView.context, "Status: ${gameDetail.isGamePlayed}",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        )
            .show()

        holder.game = gameDetail
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return oneTwoGames.size
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code that reads the data from Firestore.

Comment: That's incomplete. Please the entire code that you're using to read the data.

Comment: I hope now that is what you are asking for

Comment: Did UndefinedBug1.0's answer solve the problem?

Comment: No. It didn't solve. It gives same results as mine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your `for` loop where you are using `documents` instead of `document` within the loop so it overwrites the list on every iteration and sets adapter again and again. Do it like this:

First declare `Game` list globally:

```
private val gameList = ArrayList<Game>()
```

Now add every document to the `gameList` in each iteration and pass this list to the `adapter`:

```
for(document in documents) {
    val gameObject = document.toObject(Game::class.java)
    gameList.add(gameObject)
}

binding.oneTwoGamesRecyclerview.adapter = OneTwoAdapter(gameList)
```

Also, change `adapter` constructor parameter to `ArrayList` instead of `MutableList`.

P.S: Always copy paste the code in questions rather than uploading screenshots. It helps us to reproduce the bug more easily.

Comment: Hello, am getting same results as before.